# While loop is only printing out the first array in a 2d array

Tags: c

The first while loop should go on while i < 3, but the initial loop will only print the first array of the 2d array initialized above, and then it breaks out of the while loop after i++. I'd like for it to print all of the arrays inside of the array, not just the first one.

I'm aware that this can be done with a for loop, but if it works with a for loop it should work with a while loop - yet I can't find a way to make it work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int array[3][3] = { {6, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {0, -1 -2};
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    
    while(i < 3) {
            while(j < 3) {
                    printf("%d, ", array[i][j]);
                    j++; }      
              i++; printf("\n"); }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Because you forgot to reset `j`. Move `int j = 0;` to *inside* the outer loop.

Comment: reset j to 0 after the inner loop finishes.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for the help! I managed to somehow overlook that.

Comment: More simply, put the declaration and initialization of `j` at the beginning of the outer loop.

Comment: Why not just use a `for` loop, then it's harder to get it wrong.

Comment: @Barmar I just thought to try it with while loops because if I did it with a for loop, I should be able to do it as a while loop, so it was kind of an experiment. When I couldn't get it to work, I was a little confused and couldn't figure out why it wouldn't. I hope that answers your question

Comment: You're right that every for loop can be converted to a while loop. And if you did that, you would have gotten the right result -- the `int j = 0;` line would be immediately before `while (j < 3)`

Comment: @Barmar Ahhh I see. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: A debug hint: replace `printf("%d, ", array[i][j])` with `printf("i:%d j:%d v:%d\n", i, j, array[i][j])` and you'll certainly see what's going on here.